# Convert a range of cells from Decimal to Two's Comp

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm currently creating a tool and teaching myself excel vba at the same time. I'm not a programmer but for the purpose of this task I am.

I'm trying to convert decimal numbers from a range of cells into two's comp (using 16 bit binary) so that I can multiply this by a scaling factor. I've seen several pieces of code around the net on how to do this for singular values and cells but nothing on a range.

[Here](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/12/02/decimal-to-binary/) is a link to a page I found rather useful but I'm still unsure of how to code it or even how it works.

Apologies for a bit of a noob style question and I usually post what I have tried (if needed), but I honestly do not know where to start with this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you could explain more about how two's comp works so that we have a better idea of what output you want?

Comment: Start by enabling the developer mode on Excel. Draw an ActiveX button and insert the code you linked to the button. Try to tweak the code and, if it fails, come here with the code and the tweaks you made.

Comment: You need to look for the code to loop a range of cells in excel, then pass the cell value into the function in your example.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll let you know what I come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point types are *already* stored as IEEE 754 internally, so there isn't any reason to re-convert them using VBA - just copy them directly from memory to a non-floating point type with the same width.  Note that VBA doesn't have a native 16 bit float type - the shortest is the 32 bit `Single`.  This will copy a `Single` into a `Long` (which has a twos complement layout):

```
'In a module
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias _
    "RtlMoveMemory" (ByVal Destination As LongPtr, ByVal Source As LongPtr, _
    ByVal length As Long)

Public Function SingleToTwosComplement(data As Single) As Long
    Dim retVal As Long
    CopyMemory VarPtr(retVal), VarPtr(data), LenB(retVal)
    SingleToTwosComplement = retVal
End Function
```

If you're using a 64 bit version of Office, you can do the same thing with a `Double` into a `LongLong`:

```
'64 bit VBA only.
Public Function DoubleToTwosComplement(data As Double) As LongLong
    Dim retVal As LongLong
    CopyMemory VarPtr(retVal), VarPtr(data), LenB(retVal)
    DoubleToTwosComplement = retVal
End Function
```

On 32 bit Office, you'd need to copy it into a pair of Longs or some other structure that was 64 bits wide.

Use it like this:

```
Public Sub Usage()
    Dim foo As Single
    foo = 3.14159265359
    Debug.Print SingleToTwosComplement(foo)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Comintern, thanks for your answer. I am using a 32-bit version of Excel. The top part of that code however keeps coming up with "Only comments allowed after End Sub". Either way, being as I am a noob to this, would you just explain a bit more about what is going on here? Thanks.

Comment: @MattGriffin - The `Public Declare` bit needs to be at the very top of the module (after `Option Explicit`).  All it's doing is copying the exact binary representation of a floating point number (IEEE 754 `Single`) into a twos complement variable type (`Long`) without allowing VBA to perform a cast on it.  This gives you access to its the in-memory layout.

Comment: ah ok cool I understand now, thanks! I'm getting an error though that says "Argument not optional" despite not having any optional declarations on the SingleToTwosComp part.

Comment: @MattGriffin - How are you calling it?  You have to pass it a value.

Comment: Sorry I've been away for the last few days. I'm trying to pass it a range of cells from my datasheet so I'm not sure if it's having an issue with that.

Comment: I've managed to get it to loop through my range of cells but it's not outputting a correct value. For example, if I enter 51234 and convert it to 2's comp it should come out as -14302, however, the code outputs it as a huge number (`1E+09`). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @MattGriffin - Maybe I'm not exactly clear on what you intend to do - almost *any* floating point number will look be huge if you treat it as twos complement because [the exponent is in the high order bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32).

Comment: I intend on converting a decimal number to two's comp, to then multiply it, so I can convert it to an angle (e.g. 90 degrees).

Comment: @MattGriffin - That basically just restating "convert decimal numbers from a range of cells into two's comp (using 16 bit binary) so that I can multiply this by a scaling factor" from the question. By "multiply it", do you mean "change the exponent bits"?